# Is there a way to parse a url string when making a select to the column in big query?

Tags: sql, split, substring, google-bigquery

If I have dataset test_dataset and test_table and want to only pull the id numbers from the urls when making a select. Is there a way to do this in standard bigquery sql?

i.e. 
the table I have

```
url_name
http://www.website.com/ids/1234567/subfolder/data
http://www.website.com/ids/2345678/subfolder/data
etc
```

What I would like to do

```
select DISTINCT(only_ids from url_name) as ids from test_dataset.test_table

# Output
ids
1234567
2345678
etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, `REGEXP_EXTRACT` and look for numbers in your url:

```
WITH data AS (select urls as url from YOUR_TABLE_NAME)
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r"([\d]+)")
  AS ids
FROM data;
```

Which will give you your desired output.

```
Row ids 
1   1234567
2   2345678
```

You can find more information about the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function in the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract).